# Update Model only changed properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to track only the Model changed value from view. For instance i have Model named `SampleModel`

```
public class SampleModel
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string ImageUrl1 { get; set; }
   public string ImageUrl2 { get; set; }
}
```

How to check only for changed Model Value inside controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you might need some form of the DTO pattern.

Say for instance you want to have different forms for the 'create' and 'edit' action, then you'll make the following:

One class for the new form:

```
public class NewSampleModelDto
{
   [Required]
   public string ImageUrl1 { get; set; }

   public NewSampleModelDto() { }

   public SampleModel ToModel() 
   {    
        return new SampleModel 
        { 
            ImageUrl1 = ImageUrl1
        };
   {
}
```

one class for the edit form:

```
public class EditSampleModelDto
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string ImageUrl2 { get; set; }

   // default constructor required for mvc model binding
   public EditSampleModelDto() { }

   // from model ==> dto
   public EditSampleModelDto(SampleModel sampleModel) 
   { 
        Id = sampleModel.Id;
        ImageUrl2 = sampleModel.ImageUrl2;
   }

   // from dto ==> model
   public void UpdateModel(SampleModel sampleModel) 
   {    
        sampleModel.ImageUrl2 = ImageUrl2;
   {
}
```

This gives you the flexibility of being able to define custom validation logic per form. 
To keep your code DRY, you can make a base SampleModelDto where you provide a constructor that handles all the 'model ==> dto' logic. You can also put display attributes on your properties here.

Anyway, if you use these DTO's in your forms and submit them to your controller, you are much more free to specify your validation and update logic.

Comment: But what you told is of separating properties with various models. But i am not only be having `ImageUrl1` and `ImageUrl2`. It may be of `n` properties.

Comment: Yes I know. That's why you would make a base Dto class, to avoid repetitive code as much as possible. However, you will be required to at least write some 'UpdateModel' code for every form you make. 

You can avoid a lot of manual code by using an automatic value mapper framework such as AutoMapper or ValueInjecter. However, do know that these come at a slight performance cost and an initial learning curve. I've also found that complex updating logic (starting with collection properties, for example) can be a hassle when you use these frameworks.

Comment: If you want to read more about ValueInjecter, I've fiddled around with it and wrote about it on my blog here: http://amoerie.com/2012/12/22/automatic-injection-of-models-to-nested-data-transfer-objects-dtos-and-vice-versa-with-valueinjecter/ 

You'll also find more code samples there.

Answer (score 2):

The controller only knows what values are coming in from the request. To reliably determine what has changed, you need to compare the received model to the current model as obtained from your (repository/dao/dal/whatever) in your controller action logic or business layer logic, wherever is more appropriate for your application.

Comment: No the case occurs during edit operation. So in my example i will be already having value for `ImageUrl1` but now only `ImageUrl2` may change. So i need to update that `ImageUrl2` alone.

Comment: I thought `tuespetre's` answer was fairly appropriate. If it doesn't answer your question can you explain more or edit your question to clarify it?

Comment: @RowanFreeman `The controller only knows what values are coming in from the request`. What i meant is some property may have values before but this time i will update only some properties and i need to track that change alone. Hope you understand

Comment: Tuespetre is correct.  There is no native way to do this.  The only values you *start* with are from the request.  This will have to be custom code.  For instance,  you could serialize the "original" model as a field on the form, and then compare them it in your action

Comment: SSS, to track any changes between the information submitted from the view and the original information, you will need to load up the original information server-side to compare to the input data. Now, it seems like you also may want to prevent ImageUrl1 from updating and only allow ImageUrl2 to change? In that case, you would use the `Bind` attribute to exclude any read-only properties of the model, as such: `public ViewResult Edit([Bind(Exclude="ImageUrl1")] SampleModel model)`

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you want, you may use jQuery for this purpose. For examp, you may create hidden div for old value and compare it with current value. If current value is equal to old value you don't need to post it.

```
<script>
$('oldValue').hide();

$(#ok).click(function())
{
var ImageUrl1;
if ($(newValue).val() != $(oldValue).val())  
    $post(.....)
});

</script>


<div class="oldValue">@Model.ImageUrl1</div>
<div class="newValue">........</div>

<button id="ok">ok</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way to do this, though there are some options.  Because you do not tell us which persistence framework you are using (ef, linq2sql, lightspeed, subsonic, etc etc) we can't say if there is a native way from *that* framework.

1. Serialize the starting model as a form field. On the server side deserialize it and compare it to the model MVC gave you from the POST.  I usually use Newtonsoft.Json and UrlEncode it.
2. For each model field, add an `<input name="field_original" value="....">` and then compare them one at a time on the server side, e.g. `Model.Name == Form["name_original"]`
3. Use jQuery to track if an input has changed, and save that as a hidden input.  E.g. `if (Form["name_modified"] == "true")) { _save name_ }`
4. Use jQuery to do some other fancy tracking system.  There are just too many options. For example,  you can add a "data-originalValue" attribute to each input with the original value. Then before form submit you can check each item, and update another `<input>` with the names of the changed properties.
5. Get the original entity your model was based on from your data store.  Manually check each field, and update only those that were changed.
6. If your persistence layer supports change tracking (like EF)
7. Get the original entity
8. Update the values in the entity with values from the Model
9. *Make sure that setting the same value as existing does not mark the property as changed*
10. Save the entity (it should only save the modified fields)

###Example of #1 above

```
<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="OldModel" value="@Url.Encode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))"/>
    <!-- the rest of  your model fields --!>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Url)
```

Controller Method

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MyModel model) {
    var oldModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(
                        HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Form["OldModel"]));
    if (oldModel.Url != model.Url) { 
        // code to save the Url field only
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome.  I wrote it the short way, but I've fixed the code so it should actually compile now.  Form = Request.Form, etc. I forgot to include the `UrlDecode` part the first time around